# skype consumes 100% cpu on idle unles it has admin privileges

Tags: windows-7, skype, resource-usage

on my rather old ,6yo core two duo intel machine, skype consumes 100% CPU Resources, when i start it without admin rights. Otherwise it will consume the usual amounts of cpu.
How can i prevent skype from using so much cpu?
Also there is another Issue when i execute skype without Admin rights: i now always need to kill the process with the task-manager.

The skype version is: 6.11.0.102
windows auto updates are enabled.

Comment: Update Skype to latest version (6.13.0.104). In case it doesn't help, try creating a new standard (i.e. non-admin) account, and see whether the CPU usage is any different there.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-using-high-CPU/td-p/2113581) may be of some interest to you. I know it's a thread about Windows 8, but it doesn't hurt to try.

It simply states that if your default browser is Google Chrome, try switching it to something else. It doesn't need to be Internet Explorer, Firefox and Opera should be just fine.

Comment: i see because my admin account has its default browser set to something other then chrom this will work but is there a solution rather then a workaround?

Comment: From what I'm reading, this issue has stemmed from version 6.9 and onward...You'd think they'd hunt down the issue by version 6.11, but it is Microsoft (NOT HATING, just saying...) - As far as I can tell, there is no "fix" for this currently...Just workarounds. People claim that going into Skype's options and disabling "show ads" fixes it. I personally don't use Skype, so I can't test this myself. If worse comes to worse, you can always try and use [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/) - It supports Skype conversations as well!

Comment: Skype = Microsoft, Microsoft's browser = Internet Explorer. Chrome is the competition, therefore Microsoft sees no great need to fix the issue, after all, you can just use Internet Explorer. An independent Skype would have to fix the issue, a Skype owned by Microsoft has all the time  in the world.

Comment: I can't believe this worked! I didn't even fully change my default browser away from Chrome. All I did was associate the .htm (not .html) file type with Internet Explorer and it did the trick.